# Non-toxic materials for edging garden

Tags: materials, gardening

I'm looking for a edging for my garden which is non-toxic. I've currently got pressure treated lumber (supposedly it is not arsenic laced). I've been stapling chicken wire to the top of the lumber to keep out rabbits (this has been working), so I'd like to continue to use pressure treated lumber, but as I understand it, they no longer sell it without the chemical treatments.

Is this true? Any ideas as the best way to "seal" off my garden area? I've tried plastic edging and found it incredibly frustrating. I guess if there were some trick to installing it, I'd consider it, but I still need to be able to seal the area off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used cedar for a number of years on garden projects with great luck. You can get the fence pickets relatively inexpensively as well. I use them (cut into 1' lengths) to build my above ground planters, and laid out lengthwise to build a box around the garden for mulch/fence supports.

Comment: Even though I am using my answer, I'll give you the green :)

Answer (score 1):

@iivel

After reading the following:

http://www.finegardening.com/design/articles/pressure-treated-wood-in-beds.aspx

It doesn't sound very threatening, so I'm just going to go ahead with the configuration I had (which is stapling chicken wire to the wood edging)